# How to handle single entries of a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called Projects. It contains a text-area "project description" and a repeater image field. I know that I can use  the function WP_Query to return an array containing all my Projects post. This works when I want to show all the projects in one page. My question is how do I handle single entries in the Projects post type. More specifically, I want to know about the function that returns reference to a single entry of Project post type and the template file to be edited so as to achieve the styling of that single custom post page.

Comment: You probably want to create a `single-{post_type}.php` template in your theme folder. `{post_type}` is the string you have passed to [`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) as the first argument. Start trying to copy you theme's `single.php` file. More on the template hierarchy [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Comment: Thanks. That answers the second part of the question very well. Can you tell me what function to use to get a reference to the particular entry that I will be styling through the mentioned single-{post_type}.php . I have coded the page that displays all the projects excerpt. Now I want the user to be able to have a full display of all the contents of a single project that he clicks on.

Comment: You don't need to call any specific function. When you visit a single custom post type entry, the content is parsed through [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). You don't need to create a new query, the query is already created by WordPress. What you need to do is just run your `while ( have_posts() )` boucle and style the content within. For example, have a look at how it's done in the [_tk theme(https://github.com/Themekraft/_tk/blob/master/single.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments the single view of your CPT will be handled according to [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). Within appropriate template you can use template tags normally, so simply `get_post()` without arguments will get you a current instance.

It is a little more tricky if you want to refer to a *specific* post in code outside of its context.

The most reliable within custom site is hardcoding its ID. Personally I also use `get_page_by_title()` (despite name can work on arbitrary post type) which is easier for human to read, but depends on title staying unchanged.